# How to fix java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry while doing android studio cocos compile?

Tags: java, gradle, build, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

While performing cocos compile for proj.android-studio

```
cocos compile -m debug  -p android -NDK-MODE debug --app-abi armeabi --android-studio
```

I am getting the below exception.

Execution failed for task ':BreakPots:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/util/LongSparseArray.class

Please have a look at my build.gradle in licocos2dx module in Android Studio.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22

    }
    sourceSets.main {
        aidl.srcDir "../java/src"
        java.srcDir "../java/src"
        manifest.srcFile "AndroidManifest.xml"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: '../java/libs')
    compile project(':facebook_lib')


}
```

Project structure showing libs screenshot:
[image]
My Android.mk file contents

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../cocos2d)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../cocos2d/external)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../cocos2d/cocos)
$(call import-add-path, $(LOCAL_PATH))

LOCAL_MODULE := cocos2dcpp_shared

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libcocos2dcpp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
../../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
../../../Classes/GameScene.cpp

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -DSDKBOX_ENABLED
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -landroid \
-llog

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../Classes

LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := PluginSdkboxAds \
sdkbox \
PluginReview \
PluginAdMob \
PluginFacebook \
PluginOneSignal \
PluginSdkboxPlay

# _COCOS_HEADER_ANDROID_BEGIN
# _COCOS_HEADER_ANDROID_END


LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static

##LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += PluginAdMob
##LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += sdkbox
##LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += android_native_app_glue
##LOCAL_LDLIBS += -landroid
##LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
##LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += PluginSdkboxPlay
##LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += PluginOneSignal
##LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += sdkbox

# _COCOS_LIB_ANDROID_BEGIN
# _COCOS_LIB_ANDROID_END

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH))

$(call import-module,.)

$(call import-module, ./sdkbox)
$(call import-module, ./pluginsdkboxads)
$(call import-module, ./pluginreview)
$(call import-module, ./pluginadmob)
$(call import-module, ./pluginfacebook)
$(call import-module, ./pluginonesignal)
$(call import-module, ./pluginsdkboxplay)

# _COCOS_LIB_IMPORT_ANDROID_BEGIN
# _COCOS_LIB_IMPORT_ANDROID_END
```

Answer (score 2):

I am answering this myself because none have responded.

I fixed it myself. The solution is so simple. I have two build.gradle files. Each one for each module.

In "App" module's build.gradle file, made android compile sdk version and target as 23. But in "libcocos2dx" module's build.gradle file, made android compile sdk version and target as 22. That is the reason for all this drama.

In both the build.gradle file, Made version as 22 and it worked like charm.

Update:

I have increased the version to 23 later and came up with another gradle build issue with "org.apache.....". I have fixed it by adding the below line in build.gradle file of "libcocos2dx" module.

```
android {
   useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```